# Add nodes to kubernetes cluster on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes

I initially setup a cluster with the `kube-up.sh` utility on AWS. Now I ran out of capacity and I'm looking for a simple way to extend my cluster with more nodes.

Is there a 'simple' way to add more nodes to a running cluster on AWS? I've been reading all the docs but cannot seem to find a way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not "simple", but if you clone the set up on one of your nodes, it will automatically register itself with the master.

Basically you need to clone the kubelet configuration and authorization tokens.

You will also need to set up advanced networking to route packets to the subnet of the node.  Again, if you look at the config of an existing node, you should be able to emulate what needs to happen.

This is one of the places where Google Container Engine makes things easier, scaling is integrated into the console experience.

Eventually someone may support Amazon autoscaling groups, but for now this sort of thing is definitely better supported on the Google Cloud Platform.

Comment: Thanks Brendan. Sorry for the late reply. I did some tests and it looks like if I go the AWS EC2 dashboard and then I select a minion and then click "Launch more like this" under 'Actions', the minion comes up and registers just fine. This is not the idea solution but it works. Removal works the same way.

Comment: @FlorianRosenberg thanks for asking this question - would you mind clarifying "Removal works the same way"? Is the "correct" way to scale down is to just stop a node and have kubernetes recover?

Comment: Yes, I stopped the node and have k8s recover. This works for me. Not sure this is "correct" though.

Answer (score 15):

If you used kube-up, your minions should be launched into an auto-scaling group, and you should just be able to change the size of that auto-scaling group.

This question is a few months old, so I'm not sure whether this was the case back in July, but it should definitely be the case now.

I'm also working on launching the master into an auto-scaling group, so that if the master dies it is automatically restated, but that is a little more complicated because of the persistent disk.  But hopefully I'll make 1.1!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Did you make any progress on autoscaling for master?